# My rundll32.exe file is corrupt, how do I fix it?

Tags: windows-xp, virus

The other day I got a virus on my laptop (Windows XP), but Adaware found it and removed it. Not soon enough though, because it corrupted my rundll32.exe file. Now I can't run almost any application and I have tried to install a couple programs to fix my registry, but I can't even run the install file.

What other options do I have besides re-installing my OS?

Answer (score 2):

Doing a repair install might be an option.

**Edit:** [Here](http://michaelstevenstech.com/XPrepairinstall.htm) is a nice how to with everything important to know.

Comment: And how do you go about doing that?

Comment: @wahle509: Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my problem:

Download exefix.reg, run it, and restart. It should repair the registry so you are able to run .exe files.